# highlight weekends using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I haven't found any history questions about this... I want to highlight the weekend performance for a ggplot graph, so that user could tell directly one the graph which part(may be a gray shade?) is weekend performance right away.

Here's a simple version of testing data:

```
test <- data.frame(DATE=seq(from = as.POSIXct("2014-07-16 01:00"), to = as.POSIXct("2014-07-30 00:00"), by = "hour"),count=floor(runif(336,1,100)))
```

Simple version of my graph is:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=DATE,y=count),data=test) + labs(title="test")
```

So that result could be like something below...

[image]

Comment: See [geom_rect](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_rect.html)?. Should do what you're after. Also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504349/can-a-portion-of-the-background-in-ggplot-be-changed-to-a-different-color) may help.

Comment: @AdamKimberley Nice thanks! I can actually specify the date instead of the cell position. Think I need to come up a smarter way in longer time range but so far this works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's code that does both weekends in your data. You could generalize to any number of weekends by adding more geom_rect() calls (or calling a loop that does).

```
# your data
test <- data.frame(DATE=seq(from = as.POSIXct("2014-07-16 01:00"), to = as.POSIXct("2014-07-30 00:00"), by = "hour"),count=floor(runif(336,1,100)))
your_plot <- ggplot(test) + geom_line(aes(x=DATE,y=count)) + labs(title="test") 

# get all the start and end points
library(lubridate) # for hour function
sats <- which(hour(test$DATE)==0 & weekdays(test$DATE)=='Saturday')
suns <- which(hour(test$DATE)==23 & weekdays(test$DATE)=='Sunday')

# do your plot plus weekend highlights
your_plot +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=DATE[sats[1]], xmax=DATE[suns[1]],
                  ymin=min(count), ymax=max(count)),
            fill='yellow', alpha=.005) +

  geom_rect(aes(xmin=DATE[sats[2]], xmax=DATE[suns[2]],
                ymin=min(count), ymax=max(count)),
            fill='yellow', alpha=.005)
```

[image: Here's the output]

Comment: Nice! I just followed Adam's suggestion specify the date, but this is exactly what I was looking for regarding to longer time range. Thanks! :)

Comment: How about mentioning that the hours and weekdays functions are in the lubridate package?

Comment: Good point. Added. (Though it's just hour. weekdays is in base)

Comment: You can also use `data.table::hour`

Comment: If you're using a loop to add more geom_rect(), dont forget to use aes_string() instead of plain aes(). Otherwise only the last rectangle will be shown.

Answer (score 12):

Using geom_area() is more concise, and will work for any date range.

```
    library(ggplot2)

    test <- data.frame(DATE=seq(from = as.POSIXct("2014-07-16 01:00"), 
                                to = as.POSIXct("2014-07-30 00:00"), 
                                by = "hour"),
                       count=floor(runif(336,1,100)))

    test$weekend <- weekdays(test$DATE) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")

    ggplot(data=test, aes(x=DATE, y=count)) +
      geom_area(aes(y=weekend*max(count)), fill="yellow") +
      geom_line() +
      labs(title="test")
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for a faceted plot, but I found a useful clue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51092214/faceting-based-on-geom-point-when-ggplot-empty-and-multiple-shaded-geom-rect-e

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach using **Tydiverse tools**, and more precisely [`geom_tile`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_tile.html). The advantage is that you have not to precise the `x` boundaries.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

test %>%
  # My preference :-)
  rename_all(tolower) %>%
  # Computing the weekends by converting in weekday starting on monday to ease the cut
  mutate(weekend = wday(date, week_start = getOption("lubridate.week.start", 1)) > 5) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = count)) +
  # And here is the trick!
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("alpha", "yellow")) +
  geom_tile(aes(
    x = date,
    y = min(count),
    height = Inf,
    fill = weekend
  ), alpha = .4)
```

[image: Result]

*Note: I've written a more detailed [post](https://www.back2code.me/2020/03/display-weekends-in-r-using-tsibble/) on this topic.*

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, hopefully this is what you are looking for:

```
test <- data.frame(DATE=seq(from = as.POSIXct("2014-07-16 01:00"), to = as.POSIXct("2014-07-30 00:00"), by = "hour"),count=floor(runif(336,1,100)))

ggplot() + geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.POSIXct("2014-07-26 00:00"), xmax = as.POSIXct("2014-07-28 00:00"), ymin = 0, ymax = 100), fill = "yellow")+
 geom_line(aes(x=DATE,y=count),data=test) + labs(title="test")
```

Giving pretty much exactly the image in the question. You can alter fill to change the colour and easily add further rectangles at different points if required.

[image: Resulting image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice solution with `geom_bar()` where you make a vector which is infinite on weekends, the remaining values are NA and will not be plotted. I used `lubridate` as I am more familiar with it. I also had to name the aesthetics in the first call to `ggplot()` so the axes inherit their proper names and `y` is not labelled as "weekend":

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

test <- data.frame(DATE=seq(from = as.POSIXct("2014-07-16 01:00"), to = as.POSIXct("2014-07-30 00:00"), by = "hour"),count=floor(runif(336,1,100)))
your_plot <- ggplot(test) + geom_line(aes(x=DATE,y=count)) + labs(title="test") 
your_plot

test$wd <- wday(test$DATE, label = TRUE)
test$weekend[test$wd=="Sat" | test$wd=="Sun"] <- 1/0

highlight_plot <- ggplot(test, aes(x= DATE, y = weekend)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="Identity", aes(y=weekend), col="yellow", alpha=.4, width = 1) + 
geom_line(aes(x=DATE,y=count)) + labs(title="test") 

highlight_plot
```

This solution is pretty flexible and it's easy to adapt the method to highlight different vectors of dates.